# how to fix eol while scanning string literal in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, ascii

I have created a program in Python to turn compressed rle data into text with the first two numbers in a string being the number of times the 3rd character is repeated.  But my decompression algorithm is coming up with the error in Python 3.7:  `eol while scanning string literal`.  Please can you help?

```
s = ("""
01,01a01d57801d01a01,
01e05r65t
""")
pairs = [(int(s[i:i+2]), s[i+2]) for i in range(0, len(s), 3)]
text = ('').join(n * c for n, c in pairs)
print (text)
```

The expected result from `'01,01a01d57801d01a01,'` is `',ad888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888da,'` but I get `eol while scanning string literal`.

Comment: Unable to duplicate with your posted code.  Your actual code must have something different - perhaps a mixture of single and double quotes around that string.

Comment: The error message you posted (EOL in string literal) is a parsing error.  This mean that the program does not get to start running at all but translating it to byte code already fails.  You probably have forgotten a closing quote or similar.

Comment: You might be using typographical quotes instead of ASCII quotes: `“` or `”` or even `¨` instead of `"`.

Answer (score 0):

## This error commonly happens when a string is not written correctly (usually the quotes are in the wrong positions or they are not the correct quote marks).

The normal format of a string is this:

```
string = "This is a string." # I recommend not doing triple quotes (" " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

if you try to change your code like this:

```py
      1 for i in range(0, len(s), 3):
      2     print(i)
----> 3     print(int(s[i:i+2]), s[i+2])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ',0'
```

you can get `i` value like this:

````py
0
0 1
3
``
ok, let try this:

```python
In [4]: s[3:5]
Out[4]: ',0'
````

see it? you can‘t give int function character。I mean can't give any no number character。